# jQuery Multiple Datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want different hostels in my system can choose the date and time to close it.

On the hostel side, it is done and data is stored in the database.

But on the client side, I make various boxes that include the hostel's name and details.

When the client clicks, it should show the date and time that the hostel is available in the calendar.

The date set by the hostel will become disabled in the calendar.

My problem is when I clicked different hostel, they will only show me the result of the first hostel.

It means the date disabled is the same for every hostel.

In my code, I use `foreach()` for the loop to show all the hostel names and details.

Here is my code

```
<center>
    <div class="form-control datepicker" name="date">
        <input class="form-control" name="appdate" type="text" readonly />
    </div>
</center>

<?php 
    $result = mysqli_query($mysql, "SELECT * FROM `exdate` ") or die(mysqli_error($mysql));
    $user = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>

<script src="assets/js/datepicker/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Get all datepicker elements
    var datepickers = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');

    // Assign names to each datepicker element
    datepickers.forEach(function(datepicker, index) {
        var name = 'datepicker' + (index+1);
        datepicker.setAttribute('name', name);
    });
</script>

<script>        
    var disableDates = [<?php foreach ($user as $row) {
                        echo "'" . $row['datedisable'] . "'" . ",";
                    } ?>];

    $(function () {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({ 
            autoclose: true,
            todayHighlight: true,
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            startDate: new Date(),
            daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
            // datesDisabled: datesForDisable
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
                if (disableDates.indexOf(dmy) != -1) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }).datepicker('update', new Date());
    });
</script>
```

when I clicked a different tab, it will show me the different calendars that include their own disabled date. But I tried also not successful. I had tried to change the name for them like datepicker1, dateicker2,...

Comment: Can you share the rendered JavaScript of the `disableDates` assignment instead of the PHP?